# Unable to install Ubuntu on Asus pro WS WRX80E-SAGE SE WIFI and AMDRyzen TR PR

Tags: 20.04, 22.04

After running the installer of Ubuntu 20.04/22.04 (Desktop or Server) from the usb stick, the installer crashes like in screen
I used DVD, USB stick, Ventoy for installation Ubuntu
The centos 8 distribution installs and works fine on this hardware
My computer spec:

Asus pro WS WRX80E-SAGE SE WIFI
CPU - AMD Ryzen TR PRO 5965WX
2 x NVME Samsung PRO 980 1TB
128 GB SAMSUNG ECC 4x32GB
GPU - ASUS VGA NV 2GB GT1030

Can you solve the problem for me?[the screen where the installer hangs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXYGI.jpg)

Comment: Try my answer and see if any of it works; it not PM me by leaving a comment and Ill remove it.

Comment: Are you using the Safe Boot option? That is for nVidia & similar issues.  And then also choose restricted/proprietary drivers install option to get correct nVidia driver installed. Have you updated UEFI firmware to latest available? And updated Samsung SSD to latest firmware? https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/
Look at firmware, not Magician which is Windows. If you then can boot, to see your firmware: `udisksctl status` or install `sudo apt install nvme-cli` and run:`sudo nvme list`

Answer (score 0):

These steps will help to have the boot continue:

- Disable secure/fast boot and use legacy mode
- Enter GRUB, move the selection to the first choice, and then press the Tab key to get to "edit mode"
- behind `kernel=` add:

  ```
  nouveau.modeset=0 rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau video=vesa:off
  ```

  and try to continue booting
- If that does not work do the same but instead add:

  ```
  noexitboot=1 modprobe.blacklist=nouveau rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau --- intitrd.img
  ```

  and try to continue booting

If it does and it installs afterwards go to "aditional hardware" and see if there are options for alternative drivers if any of them work without those parameters you added.