# Ubuntu installation can't find drives

Tags: system-installation, drive

so I have trouble installing Ubuntu on my workstation (Threadripper PRO 5995WX in combo with an ASUS Pro WS WRX80E-SAGE SE WiFi board | 2x8 TB SATA WDs and a Samsung Evo 980).
Thing is that when I try to install it, the partition manager doesn't show me any drives except the USB drive.
I've already checked with lsblk -l and also just saw the USB drive.
The versions of Ubuntu which I tried were 20.04 , 22.04 and 22.10.
And the BIOS settings are as followed:

SATA Mode is AHCI
NVMe RAID mode is disabled
Secure Boot is set to Other OS (which should be the equivalent to disabled on this mainboard)
CSM is also disabled

Another thing I found out is that in Windows and CentOS 9 Stream the disks are getting recognized so this seems to be a Ubuntu problem.

I would be thankful for any input on how I might be able to fix this problem.

Comment: Possible to try:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424703/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-asus-pro-ws-wrx80e-sage-se-wifi-and-amdryzen-tr-pr

Comment: Have you updated UEFI firmware & the SSD firmware. For my NVMe Samsung, I used this site & downloaded an ISO with newer firmware. https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/ I am able to see version in this: udisksctl status Generally with very new hardware you need a version of Ubuntu that is newer than when hardware released, to get kernel & drivers that support that new hardware.

Comment: UEFI is the newest version. I could try updating the NVMe but that wouldn't explain the missing HDDs, right?
Also 22.10 released last month right? Because that version also didn't work and it should be newer than the mainboard and the processor.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

The SR-IOV option needs to be enabled in BIOS.
That way the drives show up in the Ubuntu installation.